# Python: How do I compare unicode to ascii text?

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

I'm trying to convert characters in one list into characters in another list at the same index in Japanese (zenkaku to hangaku moji, for those interested), and I can't get the comparison to work. I am decoding into utf-8 before I compare (decoding into ascii broke the program), but the comparison doesn't ever return true. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Here's the code (indents are a little wacky due to SO's editor):

```
#!C:\Python27\python.exe
# coding=utf-8
import os
import shutil
import sys

zk = [
'。',
'、',
'「',
'」',
'（',
'）',
'！',
'？',
'・',
'／',
'ア','イ','ウ','エ','オ',
'カ','キ','ク','ケ','コ',
'サ','シ','ス','セ','ソ',
'ザ','ジ','ズ','ゼ','ゾ',
'タ','チ','ツ','テ','ト',
'ダ','ヂ','ヅ','デ','ド',
'ラ','リ','ル','レ','ロ',
'マ','ミ','ム','メ','モ',
'ナ','ニ','ヌ','ネ','ノ',
'ハ','ヒ','フ','ヘ','ホ',
'バ','ビ','ブ','ベ','ボ',
'パ','ピ','プ','ペ','ポ',
'ヤ','ユ','ヨ','ヲ','ン','ッ'
]

hk = [
'｡',
'､',
'｢',
'｣',
'(',
')',
'!',
'?',
'･',
'/',
'ｱ','ｲ','ｳ','ｴ','ｵ',
'ｶ','ｷ','ｸ','ｹ','ｺ',
'ｻ','ｼ','ｽ','ｾ','ｿ',
'ｻﾞ','ｼﾞ','ｽﾞ','ｾﾞ','ｿﾞ',
'ﾀ','ﾁ','ﾂ','ﾃ','ﾄ',
'ﾀﾞ','ﾁﾞ','ﾂﾞ','ﾃﾞ','ﾄﾞ',
'ﾗ','ﾘ','ﾙ','ﾚ','ﾛ',
'ﾏ','ﾐ','ﾑ','ﾒ','ﾓ',
'ﾅ','ﾆ','ﾇ','ﾈ','ﾉ',
'ﾊ','ﾋ','ﾌ','ﾍ','ﾎ',
'ﾊﾞ','ﾋﾞ','ﾌﾞ','ﾍﾞ','ﾎﾞ',
'ﾊﾟ','ﾋﾟ','ﾌﾟ','ﾍﾟ','ﾎﾟ',
'ﾔ','ﾕ','ﾖ','ｦ','ﾝ','ｯ'
]

def main():
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print("Please specify a file to check.")
    return

try:
    f = open(filename, 'r')
except IOError as e:
    print("Sorry! The file doesn't exist.")
    return

filecontent = f.read()
f.close()

#y = zk[29]
#print y.decode('utf-8')

for f in filecontent:
    for z in zk:
        if f == z.decode('utf-8'):
        print f

print filename



if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several.

```
zk = [
u'。',
u'、',
u'「',
 ...

 ...
    f = codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
 ...
```

I'll let you work out the rest now that the hard work's been done.

Comment: I assume that the `decode` call on `z` (in the original code) is meant to compensate for the fact that `zk` contains `str` objects rather than `unicode` objects, but using unicode strings in the first place as you've indicated definitely seems cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `zk` and `hk` lists contain Unicode strings. Either use Unicode literals e.g., `u'a'` or decode them at runtime:

```
fromutf8 = lambda s: s.decode('utf-8') if not isinstance(s, unicode) else s
zk = map(fromutf8, zk)
hk = map(fromutf8, hk)
```

You could use `unicode.translate()` to convert characters in one list into characters in another list at the same index:

```
import codecs

translation_table = dict(zip(map(ord,zk), hk))
with codecs.open(sys.argv[1], encoding='utf-8') as f:
     for line in f:
         print line.translate(translation_table),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert everything to the same form, and the form is Unicode strings.  Unicode strings have no *encoding* in the sense `.encode()` or `.decode()`.  When having a non-unicode string, it is actually a stream of bytes that expresses the value in some encoding.  When converting to Unicode, you have to `.decode()`.  When storing Unicode string to a sequence of bytes, you have to `.encode()` the abstraction to concrete bytes.

This way, when loading Unicode strings from an UTF-8 encoded file, or you have to read it into the old strings (non Unicode, sequences of bytes) and then `.decode('utf-8')`, or you can use `codecs.open(..., encoding='utf-8') -- then you get Unicode strings automatically.

The form `# coding=utf-8` is not the usual, but it is OK... if the editor (I mean the tool that you use to write the text) also thinks this way.  Then the old strings are displayed by the editor correctly.  In the case they should be `.decode('utf-8')`d to get Unicode.  Old strings with ASCII characters only in the same source can also be converted to Unicode using the `.decode('utf-8')`.

To summarize: you are **de** coding from bytes to Unicode, and you are **en** coding the Unicode strings into sequence of bytes.  It seems from the question that you are doing the opposite.

The following is completely wrong:

```
for f in filecontent:
    for z in zk:
        if f == z.decode('utf-8'):
            print f
```

because the `filecontent` is the result of `f.read()`.  This way it is a sequence of bytes.  The `f` in the loop is one byte.  The z.decode('utf-8') returns one Unicode character.  They cannot be compared. (By the way, the `f` is a kind of misleading name for a byte value.)